# How can I test a void method that handles matrices with JUnit?

Tags: java, matrix, junit, void

How can I test a void method that changes an integer matrix without any parameters with JUnit?

This is a Tetris project and the method to check moves a block one to the left. It "detects" a falling block with negative numbers.

```
<!-- language: java -->   
public void moveLeft() {
    if (currentX > 0 && isMovable(currentTet, currentX-1, currentY)) {
        for (int i = currentX; i < currentX + currentTet.getShape()[0].length + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = currentY; j > currentY - currentTet.getShape().length; j--) {
                if (i > board[0].length - 1)
                    board[j][i-1] = 0;
                else if (board[j][i] <= 0 && board[j][i-1] <= 0) {
                    board[j][i-1] = board[j][i];
                    board[j][i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        currentX--;
        glc.paint(board);
    }
}
```

Possible matrix before:
0  0  0 0
0 -1 -1 0
1  2  3 2
1  1  3 3

Matrix after:
0  0  0 0
-1 -1 0 0
1  2  3 2
1  1  3 3

How can I test methods like that with JUnit?

Comment: First: refactor your code to separate changing the board and painting the board. To test the `moveLeft()` method: for every significant movement case: create an initial board and a current block, and check that board and block position have the expected value after the `moveLeft()` value. A lot of work with your code: poor testability

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RalfKleberhoff. As I have not enough time until I have to submit to my course, I can't refactor all the code. How can I ignore the line glc.paint(board); during Junit Test because this line throws a NullPointerException and I can't make a new Instance of glc (glc is a Controller class for a fxml file).